# Генерация JSP страницы на Java.

Tags: java, servlet, jsp

Всем привет, у меня есть вопрос следующего характера:

У меня есть JSP страница с html формой и к ней привязан Servlet. Я хочу чтобы по нажатию кнопки на JSP странице, сервлет генерировал новую страницу страницу, т.е. создав еще 1 JSP страничку с указанной информацией на форуме предыдущей странице.  Можно ли это сделать? И какую информацию лучше всего изучить для данных действий.

Буду очень признателен за направления изучения правильного материала. Спасибо!

Update:
В общем у меня есть готовая JSP страница с формой, которая содержит следующие едиты:

Название ( это будет отображаться в шапке страницы) URL адреес ( это создает имя новой JSP страницы) т.е. сюда вводим к пример privet, оно нам создает страницу с именем privet.jsp

Другие данные.

Кнопка создать. По нажатию этой кнопки, будет создаваться JSP страница по выше сказанным данным и с указанным URL.

Comment: опишите процес более подробнее, желательно с примером каким-нибудь ;)
а то не очень понятно, что именно вам нужно

Comment: В общем у меня есть готовая JSP страница с формой, которая содержит следующие едиты:

Название ( это будет отображаться в шапке страницы) 
URL адреес ( это создает имя новой JSP страницы) т.е. сюда вводим к пример privet, оно нам создает страницу с именем privet.jsp 

Другие данные.

Кнопка создать. По нажатию этой кнопки, будет создаваться JSP страница по выше сказанным данным и с указанным URL.

Comment: что-то вы не то делаете или что-то нам недоговариваете... зачем генерировать jsp страницу? может вы не совсем правильно понимаете для чего jsp а для чего сервлеты? без генерации jsp страницы вполне можно обойтись, - пусть сервлет возвращает страницу в таком виде как та jsp которую ви планируете генерировать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для описанной Вами модели, наверное будет неплохо сделать:
 * 3 jsp(для списка турниров, для добавления одного турнира и для редактирование - если надо)
 * 3 сервлета (для добаления турнира, для отображения списка и для редактирования - опять же если требуеться такой функционал)
никаких других jsp старниц генероровать не стоит

зы если очень надо сделать пишите на мыло помогу безвозмездно, практика никогда не повредит

Comment: По идее это я сделать могу, т.е. уже делал, но есть пару проблем, не плохо было бы проконсультироваться с Вами :) А как на мыло отсюда написать не наше ;(

Comment: мыло в профеле есть

Comment: У меня его не показывает :) Может доступ какой ограничен на просмотр, не знаю.

Comment: 04pmsuu1(AT)gmail(dot)com

Answer (score 1):

Генерировать из JSP/сервлета еще одну страницу JSP - это звучит примерно как из Java сгенерировать исходный текст Java другой проги и запустить. Конечно, так иногда (крайне редко) делается. Но на это должны быть очень веские причины.

Из того, что вы говорите я пока не вижу зачем это нужно. Для простого форварда из одной на другую страницу генерировать на лету JSP - это пожалуй слишком.

Внимательно подумайте - может вы чего-то не недопонимаете?

Comment: Может и недопонимаю. Просто у меня проект, для создания турниров на WEB.

Так вот, в нем функция создания турнира. Я хочу, чтобы по нажатию оно генерировало турнир по указанным данным. Но как я не знаю и что для этого изучить надо. Поэтому и спрашиваю тут ;(

Comment: Ну и что? трудно что ли сбросить клиенту HTML сгенерированный по нажатию клавиши или сделать как разъяснил @bald2b. Или вы не понимаете, что JSP далее компилириуется в Java текст, который еще раз компилируется в объектный код и только потом выполняется?

Comment: Получается не понимаю поэтому и спрашиваю как и где про это можно узнать ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. Создаете еще один jsp файл, допустим jsp2.jsp
2. если на форме нажата кнопка, то делаете forward на второй jsp файл:

   RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("jsp2.jsp");
   dispatcher.forward(request, response);

Comment: немного не то :)

Comment: Вам именно jsp-файл сгенерировать надо? Это конечно глупо, но можно. Просто создаете файл как обычно и сохраняете :) Только приложение должно иметь write права на папку, где лежат jsp файлы.